# Как можно убрать .fadeIn(); эффект?

Tags: jquery

Как можно убрать `.fadeIn();` эффект? [Можно посмотреть здесь.](http://jsfiddle.net/syahrasi/Us8uc/)

Comment: Если Вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галочку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Заменить в js коде `fadeIn()` на `show()`, если я правильно понял Ваш вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо вам!!!!